# How do I extract a JSON value if another value is higher than zero?

Tags: json, powershell

My current code:

`Powershell -Noprofile "(Get-Content 'allacts.txt' | ConvertFrom-Json).activityid | Out-File -FilePath ids%filenum%.txt"`

This queries the JSON file (allacts.txt) and extracts a single value, activityid.

However, I don't want *all* the activityids, just the ones where the value *attendedpeoplecount* is higher than 0. How can I work that if logic into this command?

Sample:

```
[
  {
    "activityid": 610228,
    "attendedpeoplecount": 0
  },
  {
    "activityid": 568168,
    "attendedpeoplecount": 36
  }
]
```

Current command on the above json would return

```
610228
568168
```

The desired output would be

```
568168
```

Comment: Please add a sanitized sample of the JSON. It is not clear where the value `attendedpeoplecount` is to be found.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, done it now. There are lots of other key value pairs in the real thing, but those are the only relevant ones.

Comment: @NeMo I have provided an answer based on your lastest update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) Cmdlet should get you what you need.

```
Powershell -Noprofile "((Get-Content 'allacts.txt' | ConvertFrom-Json) | Where-Object { $_.attendedpeoplecount -gt 0 }).activityid | Out-File -FilePath ids%filenum%.txt"
```

**Update**: Wrapped `Get-Content` and `ConvertFrom-Json` in parenthesis

Comment: I updated my answer. I had the Where-Object in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work - it just outputs all the activity IDs

Comment: Ok tested it again - if *all* of the attendedpeoplecount are 0, then it outputs none of them. If *one* of them is greater then zero, it outputs all of them. So getting closer but not quite there.

Comment: @NeMo Answer updated

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that works. I'll report back when I've tested it thoroughly.